# would I need to use a Union here, a Join, or something else?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cant figure out if what i'm needing to do here is a Join statement, or a Union.

Pets

```
Id     name       color
1      wiskers    grey
2      midnight   black
3      ralph      yellow
4      Bob        brown
```

Shots table

```
Id   Rabbies      a123
2    Yes          No
4    No           No
```

Notes tables

```
Id    Notes
4     This pet is blind
2     This pet has no owner
```

The result im looking for:

```
Id     Name     Color     Rabbies     A123      Notes
1      Wiskers  grey      Null        Null      Null
2      midnight black     Yes         No        This pet has no owner
......
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `left join`s:

```
select p.*, s.rabies, s.a123, n.notes
from pets p left join
     shots s
     on s.id = p.id left join
     notes n
     on n.id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins and Unions are both used to combine data, and both could potentially be used here. However, I would recommend using a Join, Joins combine columns from different tables, which seems to be what you want to include. You want all columns included for a single row (for the ID of the animal).

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068500/What-Is-the-Difference-Between-a-Join-and-a-UNION

Try that link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case

```
create table Shots (id serial primary key, Rabbies varchar, a123 varchar, pet_id int); 

insert into shots  (pet_id, Rabbies, a123) values (2, 'Yes','No'), (4, 'No','No');

create table notes (id serial primary key, notes varchar, pet_id int); 

insert into notes (pet_id, notes) values (4, 'This pet is blind'), (2, 'This pet has no owner');

select p.id, p.name, p.color, s.rabbies, s.a123, n.notes
from pets p
left join shots s on p.id = s.id
left join notes n on p.id = n.id;
```